# Does software update in ICS allow to move apps to SD card?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, updates, app2sd, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S Duos - ICS 4.0.4

Since ICS 4.0.4 doesnt have the feature of moving apps to sd card, does Software Update help me to do that?
If i update the software, can i move the apps to sd card then?

Thank you for the replies! Help will be appreciated..

Comment: Android 2.2 introduced app2sd, GB had it, and ICS had it. It's only really with 4.4.x Kitkat that google completely pulled SD card access. Perhaps your device doesn't have the functionality, but my old phones always did, way before Ice Cream Sandwich (and including ICS, and JellyBean)

Comment: @RossC several manufacturers decided to remove that functionality (at least from the GUI) with ICS. But you're correct: it was not removed from AOSP before they came up with that so-called "security idea" to completely disable "free write access" to the SDCard.

Answer (score 1):

As Ross already stated in his comment, the inability to move apps to SDCard has nothing to do with Android ICS (though several manufacturers claim exactly that, it's simply not true: AOSP<sup>1</sup> supports this since [2.2-froyo](/questions/tagged/2.2-froyo) and at least up to [4.3-jelly-bean](/questions/tagged/4.3-jelly-bean). Only with the "security change" of completely disabling free write access to SDCards with [4.4-kitkat](/questions/tagged/4.4-kitkat), this feature became unavailable.

So whether an update to a higher version of Android brings back this feature to your device, depends on several factors:

- if the update is provided by the manufacturer ([stock-android](/questions/tagged/stock-android)), question is whether the manufacturer re-decided and left the option in – with the exception of Kitkat ROMs, where they are unlikely to do so.
- if you're planning for a [custom-rom](/questions/tagged/custom-rom), it's unlikely that will ship without this option. It might even have brought it back to Kitkat (the fix required to do so is not that hard to achieve) – but you might void the warranty of your device that way.

---

**<sup>1</sup>** Android Open Source Project, i.e. the Android code basis ROMs are based on

Answer (score 0):

@Viraj Mali This is the most required feature which even I wanted to have in my Galaxy trend Duos but I cannot change it as its functionality which has been removed by the manufacturer itself.

1. If the apps could be moved to SD card then the phone would perform
   better because on some devices the on board storage space is limited
   thereby making the phone slow after the installation of a number of
   apps.
2. Due to some security concerns by  some of the Android developers the
   functionality was removed.(i.e After installing an application from
   play store you cannot move it to SD Card storage).
3. It would of no of use even after installing any third party apps
   available in the play store you would still not find any move to SD
   card option.
4. This might be weird although some phones have the support even today.
5. Finally even after reading this if you still want to move the apps
   onto SD card then you would have to root the device thereby making
   your warranty void. So please be sure about it

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I clearly understood that moving apps to sd card will not be possible without rooting it.